# generate links from div click from HTML using JS

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to get my page to open a link to a page on my site after an animation (lets be corny and say a star fade)

If I have 3 cards, when I click on them, I want the same animation to play, wait 1500ms, and then open the link to the new page (in the same tab).

Id like to do this by just setting either the a href, or the window.location in HTML and then have a JS query that pulls the link information

sorry if this is too vague, its my second day with JS, and I dont know what I dont know yet

### HTML

```
<div class="link1" window.location="index1.html"></div>           
<div class="link2" window.location="index2.html"></div>
<div class="link3" window.location="index3.html"></div>
```

### Javascript

```
open() {

this.isOpened = true;

this.elm.classList.add('is-opened');

this.timeStart = Date.now();

this.renderLoop();

setTimeout(function() { window.location = document.getElementsByName('window.location')}, 1500);

  }
```

Comment: This line is incorrect: document.getElementsByName('window.location')                    getElementsByName will return a collection of elements, in your case, 3, this collection is indexed starting at zero, so it would contain elements at 0, 1, and 2. Also, I think you may want your div elements to have a name attribute of window.location if you want to even return any elements from getElementsByName, also window.location is not a valid attribute in HTML. Also you need click event handlers for your divs.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way how you could set the URLs in the attribute `data-link`. E.g.

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
for(var link of links) {
  link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {  
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.open(e.target.getAttribute('data-link'), '_blank');
    }, 1500)
  }) 
}
```

```html
<div class="link" data-link="index1.html">Link-1</div>           
<div class="link" data-link="index2.html">Link-2</div>
<div class="link" data-link="index3.html">Link-3</div>
```

If you really want to open the links in new tabs, be sure that most browsers will not allow it if 'allow-popups' permission is not set. Otherwise just replace

```
window.open(e.target.getAttribute('data-link'), '_blank');
```

with

```
window.location = e.target.getAttribute('data-link');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you're defining an attribute and trying to refer to it as name - "window.location" and document.getElementsByName returns an array, so you have to use it like document.getElementsByName[0], but that's something you don't need
2. "open" is a predefined method, use some other name and call it when a click happens on the divs

I think this is what you want

```css
function openLink(element) {
  // Do your other animation stuff
setTimeout(function() { 
  window.location = element.getAttribute("data-location");}, 1500); // element = your div element and getting the data-location attribute gives the url to open
  }
```

```html
<div class="link1" data-location="index1.html" onclick="openLink(this)">asdas</div>           
<div class="link2" data-location="index2.html" onclick="openLink(this)"></div>
<div class="link3" data-location="index3.html" onclick="openLink(this)"></div>
```

Check the working fiddle here 
https://codepen.io/ajanth2012/pen/MXaPpp